# Flutter - How can I fix it when I select a value with Dropdown using Tabbar

Tags: flutter

In my application that I am trying to develop with Flutter, I use tabbar and switch between tabs.

I have a screen where I select the city and district, but the problem is;

I can select a city and district and move on to the next tab. However, when I come back to the screen where I selected the province and district, I receive the following error;

```
Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 1619 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
               items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                 return item.value == value;
               }).length == 1': There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: ARTVİN.
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value)
```

I use GetX and share my functions with you;

My UI Codes;

```
//CityDropdown
     Obx(() => DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                      child: DropdownButtonFormField<City>(
                        key: UniqueKey(),
                        isExpanded: true,
                        isDense: true,
                        hint: Text('Lütfen İl seçiniz'),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_sharp,
                            color: AppColors.primary),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                          alignLabelWithHint: true,
                        ),
                        value: customerCreateServiceRequestController
                            .selectedCity.value,
                        items: customerCreateServiceRequestController.cities
                            .map<DropdownMenuItem<City>>((City city) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<City>(
                            value:
                                city, // Ensure this value is unique for each city.
                            child: Text(city.name ?? ''),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (City? selectedCity) async {
                          if (selectedCity != null) {
                            customerCreateServiceRequestController
                                .setSelectedCity(selectedCity);
                            print('Selected City ID: ${selectedCity.id}');
                            print('Selected City NAME: ${selectedCity.name}');
    
                            // get district list
                            await customerCreateServiceRequestController
                                .fetchDistrict();
    
                            customerCreateServiceRequestController
                                .selectCityName.value = selectedCity.name!;
                            customerCreateServiceRequestController
                                .selectCityID.value = selectedCity.id!;
                          } 
                        },
                      ),
                    )),
    
    //District Dropdown
    
              Obx(() => DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                      child: DropdownButtonFormField<District>(
                        key: UniqueKey(),
                        isExpanded: true,
                        isDense: true,
                        hint: Text('Lütfen İl seçiniz'),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_sharp,
                            color: AppColors.primary),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                          alignLabelWithHint: true,
                        ),
                        value: customerCreateServiceRequestController
                            .selectedDistrict.value,
                        items: customerCreateServiceRequestController.districts
                            .map<DropdownMenuItem<District>>((District district) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<District>(
                            value:
                                district, // Ensure this value is unique for each city.
                            child: Text(district.name ?? ''),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (District? selectedDistrict) async {
                          if (selectedDistrict != null) {
                            print('Selected District ID: ${selectedDistrict.id}');
                            print(
                                'Selected District NAME: ${selectedDistrict.name}');
                            customerCreateServiceRequestController
                                .setSelectedDistrict(selectedDistrict);
                          
                          } 
                        },
                      ),
                    )),
```

Fetch city and district value from api code

```
  Future<void> fetchCities() async {
    try {
      final response = await LocationApiService().fetchCityData();
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final CityResponseModel cityResponse =
            CityResponseModel.fromMap(response.body);
        cities.value = cityResponse.cities ?? [];
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load cities');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future<void> fetchDistrict() async {
    try {
      final selectedCityId = selectedCity.value?.id;
      if (selectedCityId != null) {
        final response =
            await LocationApiService().fetchDistrictData(selectedCityId);
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          final DistrictResponseModel districtResponse =
              DistrictResponseModel.fromMap(response.body);
          districts.value = districtResponse.districts ?? [];
          print(districts.length);

          // İlçe listesi güncellendikten sonra seçili ilçeyi sıfırla
          selectedDistrict.value = null;
        } else {
          throw Exception('Failed to load districts');
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Model code;

City Model

```
import 'dart:convert';

class CityResponseModel {
  final List<City>? cities;

  CityResponseModel({
    this.cities,
  });

  factory CityResponseModel.fromJson(String str) =>
      CityResponseModel.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory CityResponseModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      CityResponseModel(
        cities: json["cities"] == null
            ? []
            : List<City>.from(json["cities"]!.map((x) => City.fromMap(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "cities": cities == null
            ? []
            : List<dynamic>.from(cities!.map((x) => x.toMap())),
      };
}

class City {
  final int? id;
  final String? name;
  final int? countryId;

  City({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.countryId,
  });

  @override
  String toString() {
    return name!;
  }
  factory City.fromJson(String str) => City.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory City.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => City(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        countryId: json["country_id"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "country_id": countryId,
      };
}
```

District Model

```
import 'dart:convert';

class DistrictResponseModel {
  final List<District>? districts;

  DistrictResponseModel({
    this.districts,
  });

  factory DistrictResponseModel.fromJson(String str) =>
      DistrictResponseModel.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory DistrictResponseModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      DistrictResponseModel(
        districts: json["districts"] == null
            ? []
            : List<District>.from(
                json["districts"]!.map((x) => District.fromMap(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "districts": districts == null
            ? []
            : List<dynamic>.from(districts!.map((x) => x.toMap())),
      };
}

class District {
  final int? id;
  final String? name;
  final int? cityId;

  District({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.cityId,
  });
  @override
  String toString() {
    return name!;
  }

  factory District.fromJson(String str) => District.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory District.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => District(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        cityId: json["city_id"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "city_id": cityId,
      };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution;

```
class City {
      final int? id;
      final String? name;
      final int? countryId;
    
      City({
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.countryId,
      });
    
      @override
      bool operator ==(Object other) {
        if (identical(this, other)) return true;
    
        return other is City &&
            other.id == id &&
            other.name == name &&
            other.countryId == countryId;
      }
    
      @override
      int get hashCode => id.hashCode ^ name.hashCode ^ countryId.hashCode;
    
    }
```

In the above code, the `==` and `hashCode` methods for the `City` class serve the following functions:

The `==` method: This method checks whether two `City` objects are equal. If the `other` object is not of type `City` or if the `id`, `name`, and `countryId` properties are not equal, it returns false. If the objects are of the same `City` type and the respective properties are equal, it returns true.

The `hashCode` method: This method returns a unique hash value for the object. The hash value acts as a type identifier for the object and is used to ensure the uniqueness of objects within a collection. Here, the XOR (^) operator combines the hash codes of the properties.

Implementing these methods helps accurately control the equality of `City` objects when used inside a `DropdownButtonFormField`. This ensures that the `value` property of items within the `DropdownButtonFormField` is correctly checked, addressing any potential errors.

Similarly, the same logic applies to the `District` class. Properly implementing the `==` and `hashCode` methods for these two classes ensures that equality is accurately checked among the options within the `DropdownButtonFormField`.